# Creating new instances in SQLAlchemy using lookup values instead of foreign key IDs

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have an existing database an want to build an SQLAlchemy wrapper to use the DB in Python. Lookup tables like the following are commonly used in the DB:

```
class Industry(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'industry'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=True)

class IndustrySector(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'industry_sector'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    industry_id =  Column(Integer, ForeignKey('industry.id'), nullable=False)
    name = Column(String, nullable=True)
```

What I would like to do is to create a new instance of IndustrySector using the name of the industry rather than the (technical) key of the industry, i.e.,

```
new_industry_sector = IndustrySector(industry_id = 'Manufacturing', name = 'Textile')
```

instead of

```
manu_industry_id = session.query(Industry.id).filter(Industry.name=='Manufacturing').first().id
new_industry_sector = IndustrySector(name = 'Textile', industry_id = new_industry_id)
```

Obviously, above example can't work because I am filtering on the ID rather than the name. But I don't know how to get the name of the foreign-keyed table into this. Of course I could simply add a @classmethod that handles the lookup, but if there exists any built-in functionality I'd much rather use that.

Any help / pointers are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could create a constructor which will replace the string with the id value whenever an object is created.

```
class IndustrySector(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'industry_sector'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    industry_id =  Column(Integer, ForeignKey('industry.id'), nullable=False)
    name = Column(String, nullable=True)

    def __init__(self, industry_id, name):
        self.name = name
        self.industry_id = fetch_id(industry_id)

    def fetch_id(industry_id):
        # fetch and return the id
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I am doing now (was doing it with a class method as I was confused about when SQLAlchemy uses __init__ and when it uses __new__). I would expect there to be an easier, more 'pythonic' way though - some way that utilises the declared relationships between these tables

Comment: Well. SQLAlchemy's [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/constructors.html#constructors-and-object-initialization) allows us to use the `__init__` function as per our needs. I think this could be a 'pythonic' way of doing it, since it utilizes the OOPs paradigm.